# "the most recently" vs "very recently"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Could you explain, please, what is the difference between **"the most recently"** & **"very recently"**? My translator doesn't see any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Most"* is about comparing two or more items so *"most recently"* is about comparing dates (or times) and finding the smallest period before the date or time now.

*"Very recently"* just means a short period of time before now.